# Find a 3x3 matrix with only one eigenvalue with 2 corresponding linearly independent eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

The given eigenvalue is 2 with eigenvectors (0, 2, 0) and (1, -1, 2).

I tried using the formula $A=PDP^{-1}$. However, then I realize for the matrix to be diagonalizable, it needs to have 3 linear indepedent vectors and I only have 2. So I cant use this formula.

Does this question need more information to reconstruct the 3x3 matrix?

Comment: Did the question ever claim that there was a unique $3\times3$ matrix you needed to construct? Or can you just find one and be happy with it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Arthur 
The question did not state to find a unique 3 x 3 matrix. I founded that the scalar matrix of 2 is a solution to this, but just wondering if 2 eigenvectors can reconstruct a unique matrix. Or can I just choose a random third vector to be an eigenvector and construct the matrix?

Comment: You surely meant that the matrix must have an eigenvalue with two *linearly independent* eigenvectors, since once a matrix over an infinite field has an eigenvector it automatically has infinite maney as any non-zero scalar multiple of that eigenvector ie again an e.v.

Comment: @DonAntonio Ah yes, that is what I meant. The two linearly independent vectors are given in the post.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the matrix $A = PJP^{-1}$, where $$J =\begin{pmatrix}2&0&0\\0&2&1\\0&0&2\end{pmatrix} \text{ and } P = \begin{pmatrix}0&1&2\\2&-1&0\\0&2&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

The eigenvalues of $A$ are the same as the eigenvalues of $J$ since they are similar. Furthermore, $J$ has a single eigenvalue $\lambda = 2$ corresponding to eigenvectors $v_1 = (1,0,0)^T$ and $v_2 = (0,1,0)^T$. This choice of eigenvectors is not unique, but is convenient for later. One can verify that these are the only eigenvectors of $J$.

To relate this back to $A$, notice that the columns of $P$ are the desired eigenvectors of $A$, and the third column is orthogonal to the first two. Therefore, the eigenvectors of $A$ are given by $u_i = Pv_i$. To verify this, notice that $$Au_i = (PJP^{-1})(Pv_i) = PJv_i = P(\lambda v_i) = \lambda(Pv_i) = \lambda u_i.$$
Now notice that since $v_i$ are the canonical basis vectors, $Pv_i$ just equals the $i$-th column of $P$. In particular, we have that the eigenvectors of $A$ are $u_1 = Pv_1 = (0,2,0)^T$ and $u_2 = Pv_2 = (1,-1,2)^T$, as desired.

Comment: Technical detail: Just because you have two orthogonal eigenvectors, and you check that the third orthogonal vector is not an eigenvector, that doesn't mean there isn't a third (linearly independent) eigenvector. Eigenspaces can be non-orthogonal. So just checking that the "remaining vector" $(0,0,1)^T$ is not an eigenvector isn't enough to prove that your $J$ is defective.

Comment: This is true. The proper way to show this is to first see that the only eigenvalues possible are $2$ then to show the null space of $J - 2I$ is only 2-dimensional and there is no need to justify anything about the third vector unless you want it to correspond to the normal form as it does here.

Comment: But $J$ could have had an eigenspace of, say, eigenvalue $3$ spanned by $(0,1,1)^T$. Or any other non-$2$ eigenvalue with an eigenvector anywhere that's not in the $xy$-plane and not on the $z$-axis. You haven't yet ruled out all these possibilities.

Comment: I am aware of this but I guess I felt that deriving the eigendecomposition of $J$ in this answer wasn't the point of the question given that Jordan blocks are extremely well-known examples of non-diagonalizable matrices.